# Android CornerPathEffect graphical issue

Tags: java, android

When I draw a path with CornerPathEffect,

```
mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(50));
```

sometimes a glitch appear.

It's possible get it, by drawing this three points

```
mPath.moveTo(3041f/10000f * screen_width, 680f/10000f * screen_width);
mPath.lineTo(3075f/10000f * screen_width, 644f/10000f * screen_width);
mPath.lineTo(2729f/10000f * screen_width, 993f/10000f * screen_width);
invalidate();
```

What's the problem?

Comment: the [glitch image link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3072693/cornerpatheffect%20issue.png)